# Angular: Test case - jasmine - TypeError: Cannot read property 'cmd' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, integration

I'm wring an unit test case for lotame (analytics) integration. Can anyone please help me how I can write a test case for this integration? I'm stuck here quite some time. I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'cmd' of undefined`.

app.ts

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    lotame_123: {
      cmd: any;
      collect: any;
    };
  }
}

export const collectLotameData = (title: string, name: string) => {
  window.lotame_123.cmd.push(function () {
    window.lotame_123.collect({
      behaviors: {
        act: [`tracking : ${title} : ${name}`]
      }
    });
  });
};
```

app.spec.ts

```
describe('collectLotameData', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    window.lotame_123 = {
      cmd: 'sdas',
      collect: 'any'
    };
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create spy for `window.lotame_123.cmd.push()` and `window.lotame_123.collect()` methods. We create the implementation for `cmd.push()` method so that we can get the function you passed in test cases.And,we assign it to `fnRef` so that we can execute it later. After executing the `fnRef` function, we can test `window.lotame_123.collect()` method.

Here are the test cases:

`app.ts`:

```js
declare global {
  interface Window {
    lotame_123: {
      cmd: any;
      collect: any;
    };
  }
}

export const collectLotameData = (title: string, name: string) => {
  window.lotame_123.cmd.push(function () {
    window.lotame_123.collect({
      behaviors: {
        act: [`tracking : ${title} : ${name}`],
      },
    });
  });
};
```

`app.spec.ts`:

```js
import { collectLotameData } from './app';

fdescribe('collectLotameData', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const cmdSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('cmd', ['push']);
    let fnRef;
    cmdSpy.push.and.callFake((fn) => {
      fnRef = fn;
    });
    const collectSpy = jasmine.createSpy();

    window.lotame_123 = {
      cmd: cmdSpy,
      collect: collectSpy,
    };
    collectLotameData('best singer', 'teresa teng');
    expect(cmdSpy.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.any(Function));
    fnRef();
    expect(collectSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      behaviors: {
        act: [`tracking : best singer : teresa teng`],
      },
    });
  });
});
```

test result:
[image]

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/angular-v11-codelab/tree/master/src/app/examples/64104940

Comment: Please explain the _how_ and _why_ you've written the test case as this.